# How can i change all keys in a dictionary but keeping the values?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary in my code for example this:

{1: 'apples',
2: 'grapes',
3: 'melons',
4: 'bananas',
5: '...',
6: '...',
7: '...'}

now what i'm trying to deal with is removing items from this dictionary in a way that the keys don't get interupted.

what i mean is: if i remove 2: "'grapes'" the dictionary keys will have a gap where the 2 should be.

my goal:
{1: 'apples',
2: 'melons',
3: 'bananas'
4: '...',
5: '...',
6: '...'}

keep in mind that the values are random every run so the solution can't be based off the values in the dictionary.
i litterally have no idea where to start with this problem and it's been messing with my head.

i know it would be easier to turn the dictionary into an array instead but sadly i don't have the permissions to do so. It has to stay a dictionary.

thanks for your help.

Comment: That's not a dictionary, it's an object. Objects have properties.

Comment: @LucaKiebel `delete` on arrays leaves holes

Comment: @LucaKiebel `delete` wouldn't renumber the entries.

Comment: What is your use case? This  seems like an XY problem

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i know but everything in javascript is an object so i figured using the python name would make it more specific because its basicly the same thing.

Comment: recreate a new array each time something is deleted you can run a for loop trough the words array and assign number to each this for loop would be called each time something is deleted

Comment: @charlietfl the dictionary is used for ordering peoples connection to the server. so if someone visits the page they go in the first position. and so on. but if they leave the people behind them in line should be moved up.

Comment: Don't see why you can't use an array for that

Comment: @charlietfl because i don't have the permission for that as it would restructure the whole page. it would be a waste of time to change it now. though i totally agree it should be an array its too late for that now. (as i mentioned in the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, it really should be an array.

But since you presumably know the index at which you're deleting, just do the renumbering from there:

```
function remove(a, index) {
  while (a.hasOwnProperty(index + 1)) {
    a[index] = a[index + 1];
    ++index;
  }
  delete a[index];
  return a;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function remove(a, index) {
  while (a.hasOwnProperty(index + 1)) {
    a[index] = a[index + 1];
    ++index;
  }
  delete a[index];
  return a;
}

const a = {1: 'apples', 2: 'grapes', 3: 'melons', 4: 'bananas'};
console.log("before:", Object.entries(a).join("; "));

remove(a, 2);
console.log("after:", Object.entries(a).join("; "));
```

Note that on some JavaScript engines, using `delete` on an object dramatically slows access to its properties subsequently. You could create a *replacement* object instead:

```
function remove(a, index) {
  const rv = {};
  let delta = 0;
  for (let n = 1; a.hasOwnProperty(n); ++n) {
    if (n === index) {
      delta = -1;
    } else {
      rv[n + delta] = a[n];
    }
  }
  return rv;
}
```

```js
function remove(a, index) {
  const rv = {};
  let delta = 0;
  for (let n = 1; a.hasOwnProperty(n); ++n) {
    if (n === index) {
      delta = -1;
    } else {
      rv[n + delta] = a[n];
    }
  }
  return rv;
}

let a = {1: 'apples', 2: 'grapes', 3: 'melons', 4: 'bananas'};
console.log("before:", Object.entries(a).join("; "));

a = remove(a, 2);
console.log("after:", Object.entries(a).join("; "));
```

---

But again, really this should use the data structure designed for that: An array:

```js
const a = ['apples', 'grapes', 'melons', 'bananas'];
console.log("before:", Object.entries(a).join("; "));

a.splice(1, 1); // Remove the entry at index 1
console.log("after:", Object.entries(a).join("; "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Think something like this should work. you need to take care with the fact that JavaScript Objects can't have numeric keys (they've been implicitly coerced to strings).

```js
var dict = {
  1 : 'a',
  2 : 'b',
  3 : 'c',
  4 : 'd',
  5 : 'e'
};//note, that JS objects can't have numeric keys. These will be coerced to strings

function reKeyDict(obj){
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);//get an array of all keys;
  var len = keys.length;
  var greatest = Math.max(...keys);
  keys = keys.sort(function(a,b){ return a - b; });
  for(i = 1; i <= len; i++){//this needs to change if you want zero based indexing.
    if(! keys.includes(i+"")){//we need to coerce to string 
      //we found a gap
      for(var j = i+1, openSlot = i; j <= greatest; j++){
        if(obj[j] !== undefined){
          obj[openSlot++] = obj[j];
          delete obj[j];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

delete dict['3'];
delete dict['4'];
reKeyDict(dict);
console.log(dict);
```

As mentioned.. this is really not the use case for a JavaScript Object. The data structure made for this is an array. But... if you need to do it this way, hopefully this helps.

The above code is performing a stable operation (meaning the order of your original object is preserved).

Answer (score -1):

Is this an Array or is it an Object? Here's how to do it from an Object, and if it's an Array just replace the values part with the Array.

Object:

```
const obj = { 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c' }
const values = Object.values(obj) // [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
const newObj = values.reduce((acc, value, i) => {
    acc[i+5] = value // replace i+5 with whatever key you want
    return acc
}, {})
// {5: "a", 6: "b", 7: "c"}
```

Edit:
Oops... your title "How can i change all keys in a dictionary but keeping the values?" and description want opposite things to happen.